# Visualizing data using vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, machine-learning, regression

Say there are 10 houses and we have three pieces of information for each of them, area, nbedrooms, price

I can view this as 10 different vectors in space where there are 3 axes. Basically 10 arrows and each arrow represents area, nbedrooms, price for that particular vector (House). Rather than 3 pieces of information, we can more such information too, d dimensions (axes) and N rows (Houses). So far, I am good

But I am having trouble when I use such visualization in the context of linear regression, where you are predicting price, using those d-1 dimensions and N rows. Especially the column representation equation, Linearly combining areas_column_vector, nbedrooms_column_vector etc to (almost) arrive at price_column_vector

beta1*(areas_column_vector) + beta2*(nbedrooms_column_vector) + ...   = prices_column_vector

How should I even visualize these column vectors? Previously, there were N vectors in d axes. Now what? Each column vector has N dimensions now! i.e, house1_area, house2_area, ... houseN_area. Similarly N more dimensions for house1_nbedrooms, house2_nbedrooms,... houseN_nbedrooms. So for each of the (d-1) features used, there would be N dimensions (axes). Because we are taking a linear combination of all these column vectors, they must be in the same multidimensional space. In total there would be N*(d-1) axes! I must be wrong somewhere. Please suggest me a better way of visualizing such column vectors

Even in case of simple linear regression where there is only one feature (say area), beta*area_column_vector = price_column_vector. While visualizing L.H.S of this equation, I see N dimensional (N rows) area_space with 1 dimension for each house. But R.H.S is of a different N dimensional price_space. Where exactly are these two vectors? And what are the axes?

Comment: Each of those column vectors, such as areas_column_vector and prices_column_vector, belongs to $\mathbb R^N$. You are computing a linear combination of vectors in $\mathbb R^N$. There are only $N$ axes. I can only visualize $\mathbb R^N$ when $N$ is $1, 2$, or $3$. So I just visualize a linear combination of two vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ even though I'm working in $\mathbb R^N$.

Comment: So in this case, you visualize all of them as just real numbers without worrying about there physical meaning? i.e Dimension 1 shoud be seen as just house1? On this dimension, both 1000 sq.ft area and 4 bedrooms can be represented on the same axis?

Comment: If you're worried about adding together two vectors that have different units, such as areas_column_vector and nbedrooms_column_vector, you can think of the regression coefficients as having units also. $\beta_1$ has units dollars per square foot, and $\beta_2$ has units dollars per bedroom. So $\beta_1$*area_column_vector has units of dollars, and $\beta_2$*nbedrooms_column_vector has units of dollars also.